# C3646 and C4430 due to header file hierarchy?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, header-files

I'm faced with two compilation errors: C3646 and C4430. Let me show you:

I'm referring to this header file:

Timer.h

```
class Timer {
}
```

This piece of source code is working fine (in a header file):

```
#include "Timer.h"
class Something{
    Timer timer_;
```

This piece of source code is not working (in another header file):

```
class Something_else : public Singleton<Something_else> {
    friend Singleton<Something_else>;
    Timer getDebuggerTimer;
```

The compilation errors I get are the mentioned ones:

> C3646 'getDebuggerTime': unknown override specifier
>
> C4430 missing specifier - int assumed.

I have tried to include the mentioned header file `Timer.h` but this is making things even worse (I believe this file is already included via the other include entries).

Why is the compiler expecting override specifiers? (As far as I know there's no need for them, I'm just adding a property to a class?)

On the other places where it's used, the value is filled in in the constructor of the corresponding class (also in the header file). Does this have any impact on this issue?

For your information: the `Singleton` is used for implementing the corresponding design pattern.

An extra remark: the issue (at first sight) seems not to be related to namespaces.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. (Does your actual code say `Timer() getDebuggerTimer` or something similar?)

Comment: Learn to use use internet search engines. First hit on "pragma once": [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once)

Comment: The #pragma once macro makes sure that the header file is only used once. So if you do not know it the header is already included somewhere else, you almost always can include it multiple times because it will only used once.

Comment: @molbdnilo: whether or not I use the mentioned attribute somewhere in a *.cpp file, does not make any difference, so I prefer not to put this in the question, in order to keep the question as minimal as possible.

Comment: As the #pragma directive seems to create confusion, I've removed it from the existing code, and the compiler behaviour is the same.

Comment: _"I'm referring to this header file:"_ Obviously that is not the contents of your header file (it wouldn't even compile). Still need to see your [MCVE], instead of this `Something`/`Something_else` nonsense that may or may not bear any resemblance to the actual code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: _"Why is the compiler expecting override specifiers?"_ It doesn't know what to expect because it doesn't know what `Timer` is (my guess).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: the name of the header file is "Timer.h" and the code excerpt shows the piece of code which is relevant to the question. As for the name of the mentioned classes: for legal purposes I replace internal names of classes/objects by standard names, like "something" and "something_else". Obviously those names don't impact in any way the question I'm posting here.

Comment: One more time: present your [MCVE]. Your names don't have to be exactly as found in a production codebase, but you do have to present a [MCVE]. At the moment, this question cannot be answered. It's in your best interests to do as asked. If you knew which part was "relevant", you wouldn't be here asking what the problem is, would you?

Comment: Quite aside from whether a MCVE is required to answer your question or not, if you haven't constructed one yet then you haven't done your own debugging before asking us for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I've understood the root cause of the problem:

As mentioned, in the source code (header file), there's written:

```
Timer getDebuggerTimer;
```

Visual Studio's editor accepts this line of source code (no red waves under the word `Timer`), and while pressing `F12` I get into the file Timer.h, where the mentioned class is defined.

However, the compiler does not seem to agree: the compiler does not find the definition of the `Timer` class in the header file "Timer.h", but instead of saying `identifier not understood`, he gives that strange compilation message.

How did I find this out?

I've replaced `Timer getDebuggerTimer` by `BlablaTimer getDebuggerTimer`. When doing that the editor showed the hint `identifier "BlablaTimer" is undefined` but the compiler kept on giving the same compiler errors C3646 and C4430.

I'm now digging further in order to know how I can solve this issue, but I do believe that a simple `undefined identifier` should not be shown as some weird `unknown override specifier` by the compiler.