# How to add a property to a class

Tags: c++, stl

I'm working on a new application, based on templates, STL, namespaces, ... (my collegues have taken all necessary steps to make a mess), now I just want to add a property to a class, and this does not work, let me show you):

Within a header-file:

```
namespace utils{

class Logging_Manager : public Singleton<Logging_Manager> {
    friend Singleton<Logging_Manager>;

    Logging_Manager();

private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Single_Logger>> logging_modules;
    LogLevelType loglevel; // 0 : no logging, 1 : info logging, (2-4 are not used), 5 : debug, 6 : everything
public:
    Timer getDebuggerTimer;
    Timer getFileTimer;
```

I've just added the last entries `getDebuggerTimer` and `getFileTimer` myself and this does not compile, due to the compiler errors C3646 and C4430.

All I mean is that both are properties of the type `Timer`, I don't mean those things to be templates of some methods which might be abstract, virtual, or whatsoever, no they are just to meant as properties, nothing more nothing less.

As I didn't find a way to add both timers to my header file, my boss has just solved the issue as follows:

```
class Timer;    // this class is defined elsewhere, how can it be put here and make things work?
namespace utils{

class Logging_Manager : public Singleton<Logging_Manager> {
    friend Singleton<Logging_Manager>;

    Logging_Manager();

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Timer> getDebuggerTimer;
    std::shared_ptr<Timer> getFileTimer;
```

In other words: he did not add an inclusion, but he added a reference to something the header does not know: `class Timer`.

In top of this, he added a shared pointer, which magically did something.

I'm completely lost here: it looks like STL has added programming rules like:
- In case you want something to work, don't add an inclusion, but add a reference (but how does your code know what the reference means?)
- You can add shared pointers (or other STL inventions), who will make your code work.

?????

Can anybody shed a light to this?

Comment: C# background?  I'm asking because C++ doesn't define anything called "a property".  It may help to clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: And please give the complete error messages(s).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with templates or the STL.

Comment: The STL is completely innocent here, I'm not sure what you're ranting about.

Comment: Take everything you learned about C# and then forget it if you want to learn C++.

Comment: Your boss should have been able to answer this question simply. Unless he gave you reasons for not asking, I'd say next time ask your boss about it instead of asking us :-)

Comment: You're essentially missing a big chunk of C++ knowledge, among which "how to declare types". This whole question is just pointing fingers at random features that have nothing to do with the missing `#include` or declaration. Hence, VTC as "unlikely to help future readers". In your defense, MSVC's error message in this situation is incredibly unhelpful.

Comment: Also, how is this any different from [this other Q&A of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49030353/3233393)?

Comment: "compiler errors C3646 and C4430" doesn't mean very much to anyone who's not using the same compiler as you.  What's the exact (English) error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to aggregate a `Timer` into your class defintion, the compiler needs to know what a `Timer` is. So, you could use `#include "Timer.h"`(use the right header).

What your boss did is two-fold

1. use a pointer instead of a member object. Thus allowing it to work
   with a forward declaration instead of an include.
2. use a smart
   pointer instead of a raw pointer. This is good practice.

Comment: The `#include "Timer.h"` is not allowed because of circular references (although we don't find where that circular reference is: I've tried to upgrade my visual studio in order to have a graphical display of inclusions, but this caused my whole Visual Studio environment not to work anymore).

Comment: That is a whole other question. On any large-scale project I've seen there was a facility for generating the inclusion tree. When a cycle is introduced (or attempted), you look up the tree and you use a clue bat where appropriate. In this case, it smells like Timer.h is inculding too much stuff. Because aggregating a Timer smells reasonable.

Comment: But using a shared pointer is unlikely to be the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with template and STL.

You should look at what **forward declaration** is:

What your boss did with that

```
class Timer;
```

is to say to the compiler "hey look, there's something called Timer which you don't know yet, trust me and reserve for that some space".

Compiler answer ok, but it has to know how much space to allocate for costructing that object. Since you use an object and do not include the header file containing it, compiler doesn't know much space it takes and gives you an error. If you use a pointer instead (or smart pointer), the compiler does need to reserve only the space for a pointer and it can do it. Of coure then you have to include the header of time if you want to use it in the implementation.

For the same reason, you cannot forward declare a class you're going to inherit.

timer.h

```
class Timer
{
public:
   void time() { std::cout << "time!"; }
}
```

yourclass.h

```
class Timer; // forward declaration

class Manager
{
public:
  void doStuff() {}

private:
 Timer* t1; // this will work
 std::shared_pointer<Timer> t2; // this will work
 //Timer t3;  // this one don't
}
```

}

this case **does not work**:

```
class Timer;

class SpecialTimer : public Timer
{
 // ... do stuff
}
```

Some link about forward declaration:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration

[This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4757718/8805095) has a good explanation.

Comment: I do not understand the downvote